# Redirect admin-pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have created a plugin for Wordpress which extends the backend area. New menu items are available for example at [www.URL.xx/wp-admin/admin.php?page=make_request](http://www.URL.xx/wp-admin/admin.php?page=make_request).

Is it possible to set it up so that this menu item is accessible at [www.URL.xx/request](http://www.URL.xx/request)?

I alreay tried the Redirection Plugin, but this does not work. Is it possible via htaccess?

I am using Apache.

```
Redirect 301 /wp-admin/admin.php?page=make_request http://myurl.com/request
```

Does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use server redirections custom rewrites, f.e. in nginx here you can find a lot of examples --> https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/redirecting-urls-using-nginx/